# Attaching the logged-in User to object after object creation

Tags: python, django, django-models, refactoring

I am trying to have a logged in User fill out a form to create a Group. On Group creation, I need the User to automatically be added to the Group.

For this problem, we are working with two models - User and Group.

User is the default model provided by Django.

Group is defined like so:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    admins = models.ManyToManyField(User, default=1, related_name='user_username')
    all_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')

    def get_admins(self):
        return ", ".join([u.username for u in self.admins.all()])

    def add_admin(self, user):
        self.admins.add(user)

    def get_all_users(self):
        return ", ".join([u.username for u in self.all_users.all()])

    def add_user(self, user):
        self.all_users.add(user)
        self.save()

    def is_admin(self, user):
        if user in self.admins.all():
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

And the view I'm trying to refactor is:

```
@login_required
def user_generated_group(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = GroupForm(request.POST)
        user = request.user
        if form.is_valid():
            group = Group.objects.create(name=form.cleaned_data['name'])
            group.add_admin(user)
            group.add_user(user)
            group.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
    else:
        form = GroupForm()
        context = {
            'form': form,
            'type': 'group',
            'sidebar': Sidebar(request),
        }
        return render(request, 'form.html', context)
```

Here is the GroupForm:

```
class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['all_users', 'admins', ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'input'})
```

The goal is to utilize Django's built-in CreateView. The refactored view so far looks like:

```
class CreateGroup(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Group
    form_class = GroupForm
    template_name = 'form.html'
```

I have yet to implement the add_user and add_admin logic to this view. The hope is that I can manage these methods elsewhere.

I'm unsure of where to go from here. Should this logic be handled by the User or the Group?

If by the Group, should I be using a Manager?

If by the User, should I create a custom User model?

Comment: Is your `GroupForm` a `ModelForm`?

Comment: It is. I just edited the main post to include it.

Comment: See [Models and `request.user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the [**`form_valid`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.form_valid) method, to add the `self.request.user` to the group, like:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class CreateGroup(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Group
    form_class = GroupForm
    template_name = 'form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = group = form.save()
        group.all_users.add(self.request.user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```